# Delete primary key row from SQLite doesn't work

Tags: c#, wpf, sqlite

As my title describes I have a problem to delete from SQLite db.
Let me explain.
1st It's a Windows Forms Application.
2nd .NET Framework 4.8
3d Nugget package SQLite Core

My Create, Insert, Search to db works fine. I have a search which is a textBox and when the user is searching something and gets back the correct info from db it gives them an option to Update(Not implemented yet) or to Delete with 2 separate buttons(obviously). Now, my delete method gets the value from the search box and tries to delete the current row (note that the search value is a primary key from db).

When I press the Delete button my program freezes without showing immediate error, while still in process of debugging after a while it shows my that the database is locked.
CallStack says that it's going for sleep. That error occurs at the `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery` line.

I have searched all the web and here for related problems without finding something to suit me. I have an open post about this same problem in C# Forums for begginers. Haven't found a solution yet with some people trying to help me.
I'm not well versed with SQLite. I hope I provided enough information.

Here is what I'm trying this far.
**Delete.cs**

```
class Delete_Record
    {        
        string path = "Injection_Settings.db";
        public static TextBox Search_Box = new TextBox();
        public static TextBox mould_code_input = new TextBox();
        public static TextBox machine_number_input = new TextBox();
        public static TextBox machine_type_input = new TextBox();
        public static TextBox supplier_input = new TextBox();
        public static ComboBox colour_input = new ComboBox();
        public static ComboBox comboBox1 = new ComboBox();
        public static ComboBox comboBox2 = new ComboBox();
        public static ComboBox comboBox3 = new ComboBox();
        public static NumericUpDown numericUpDown1 = new NumericUpDown();
        public static NumericUpDown numericUpDown2 = new NumericUpDown();
        public static NumericUpDown numericUpDown3 = new NumericUpDown();
        public static DateTimePicker dateTimePicker1 = new DateTimePicker();
        public static TextBox item_name_input = new TextBox();
        public static PictureBox pictureBox1 = new PictureBox();
        public static PictureBox pictureBox2 = new PictureBox();

        public void Delete_Info_From_DB()
        {            
            int Mould_Code = Int32.Parse(Search_Box.Text);
            
            try
            {
                using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(@"Data Source = " + path))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    using (SQLiteCommand cmd = con.CreateCommand())
                    {
                        cmd.CommandText = @"DELETE FROM Description WHERE Mould_Code =@Mould_Code";
                        cmd.Prepare();
                        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mould_Code", Mould_Code);
                        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                        if ((cmd.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM Description WHERE Mould_Code = " + Mould_Code + "") == null)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Επιτυχής διαγραφή.");

                            mould_code_input.Text = null;
                            machine_number_input.Text = null;
                            machine_type_input.Text = null;
                            supplier_input.Text = null;
                            colour_input.Text = null;
                            comboBox1.Text = null;
                            comboBox2.Text = null;
                            comboBox3.Text = null;
                            numericUpDown1.Text = null;
                            numericUpDown2.Text = null;
                            numericUpDown3.Text = null;
                            dateTimePicker1.Text = null;
                            item_name_input.Text = null;
                            pictureBox1.Image = null;
                            pictureBox2.Image = null;
                        }    
                    }
                    con.Close();
                }                
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {               
                MessageBox.Show("Αποτυχία διαγραφής.");                
            }
        }      
    }
```

**Delete Button in Form1**

```
private void Delete_Record_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Delete_Record dr = new Delete_Record();
            Delete_Record.Search_Box.Text = Search_Box.Text;
            Delete_Record.mould_code_input = mould_code_input;
            Delete_Record.machine_number_input = machine_number_input;
            Delete_Record.machine_type_input = machine_type_input;
            Delete_Record.supplier_input = supplier_input;
            Delete_Record.colour_input = colour_input;
            Delete_Record.comboBox1 = comboBox1;
            Delete_Record.comboBox2 = comboBox2;
            Delete_Record.comboBox3 = comboBox3;
            Delete_Record.numericUpDown1 = numericUpDown1;
            Delete_Record.numericUpDown2 = numericUpDown2;
            Delete_Record.numericUpDown3 = numericUpDown3;
            Delete_Record.dateTimePicker1 = dateTimePicker1;
            Delete_Record.item_name_input = item_name_input;
            Delete_Record.pictureBox1 = pictureBox1;
            Delete_Record.pictureBox2 = pictureBox2;

            if (Database_Search.Search_Box.Text != null)
            {
                dr.Delete_Info_From_DB();
            }            
        }
```

Comment: Does the parent record you're trying to delete have child records in other tables?

Comment: No.It's still only one table and one row for testing purposes.That row has a primary key and I am trying to delete it.

Comment: Do you have an open transaction from when the row was inserted perhaps?

Comment: I made sure to use using statement everywhere and close the connection after every execution.

Comment: can someone help?

Comment: Hard to know where to start with the problem in fact I'm not even sure where to begin with the question ; you say it's a console app but then talk about textboxes and delete buttons - console apps don't have those kind of things.. There are multiple nuget packages that could reasonably be "SQLite Core" etc.. We don't really have much chance of being able to replicate the problem. Perhaps you should post the complete code on github

Comment: Caius Jard I'm really sorry about the Windows Console application.I must mistyped or someone changed it, it's a Windows Forms Application.As for the code side i think its complete fairly enough.I mean, it's only a class that i recall in my main form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my problem.I was forgeting to close the SqliteDataReader in my search methods.Thanks everyone for the help.

Comment: This should be a comment.

Comment: I don't think so. Because we should consider it as a solution to a problem. If I am wrong please tell me to delete it and make it a comment.

Comment: You can mark your own Answer as Accepted to close the question.